# Points displacement function in QGIS does not show in layer properties box

Tags: qgis, point, rendering

QGIS has a points displacement renderer (featured in section 15.1.3.1.17 at qgis.org) in the layer properties box that I need to use. However, QGIS does not show me the option of the points displacement renderer as shown in the screen shot for the qgis instructions. I think it is because my layer consists of polygons with my data displayed as centoids. I think QGIS may require me to turn the centoids in my polygon layer into a points layer before allowing me to run the points displacement renderer? But I may be wrong. My main problem is that I want to use the points displacement renderer on overlapping centoids, but QGIS does not give me the drop-down menu option to do so as shown in the qgis.org entry above. I am running 3.20.2.

Comment: I'm surpised that you didn't turn the centroids into a point layer in order to test the renderer's functionality, since you surmised that that may be a solution.

Comment: Indeed, as @StuSmith sayed: first turn it to a point layer, then make your question a bit clearer: what are "overlapping centroids"? What does not work: how should the result look like? best add a screenshot to your question, showing what is missing ("QGIS does not give me the drop-down menu option").

Comment: I cannot figure out how to turn the centoids into a point layer. The individual data points are based on large zip codes, not a specific X,Y coordinate. As a new member, I am prohibited from posting screen shots until I reach a certain level. That's why I referenced the screen shot in section 15.1.3.1.17 at qgis.org. Thanks for any help.